# When using `find ..` in rsync, rsync's --delete option is not working

Tags: command-line, rsync

I'm using

`` rsync -avh --progress --delete `find /path/to/files -type f -printf "%p\n" | sort -rn | head -n 5` /path/to/backup/ ``

to backup the newest 5 files. The `--delete` option is supposed to delete the files in the destination folder, if they are not within the 5 files which find outputs. Unfortunately the `--delete` option is not working. How to get it working or how to do what I do differently?

Comment: I think `rsync` don't know the found file is in sub-directory which `find` is looking, except current working directory `rsync` is executed

Comment: You would need rsync each of the 5 files one by one through a for loop

Answer (score 1):

[The `rsync` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) states:

> `--delete`
>
> This tells `rsync` to delete extraneous files from the receiving side
>   (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but **only for the
>   directories** that are being synchronized.

You are transmitting multiple individual files, therefore `--delete` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I'm going to replace the `--delete` by an extra command which deletes the files that come of when sorting in reverse (-r removed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't appear to have enough reputation yet to comment on your question, so I  will do so in an answer.

First, I think it would help if you posted the file names that you are working with. I also wonder what the subdirectory structure is on `/path/to/files`. I say this because I want to know if the `find` you are running is actually printing the newest files. You aren't operating on timestamps here, which why I ask. So on that note, you may want to also paste the output of the find to help clarify.

Also, I'm wondering if the `-n` on `sort` is necessary. Sorta beside the point, but you could do a `sort | tail -5`.

Without seeing more output on what your files are, including in the destination, I'm not sure that this sort of `rsync --delete` is going to work. Had this ever worked for you, or are you just now seeing this up?

Alternatively, you may look into find's -newer, -delete, and/or mtime flags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think `--delete` isn't working because `rsync` expects a directory. I think I'm going to replace the `--delete` by an extra command which deletes the files that come of when sorting in reverse (-r removed).